# Bootstrap like buttons and inputs for non bootstrap pages

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've a page which is old asp.net page also non bootstrap. Its only 1 page among 100s of pages under a master page file. But I have to update the page in some extend and been asked to make the buttons and inputs look like bootstrap style.

I linked bootstrap css to the page alone which is also working using a huge css file from the master file. This is bootstrap css I used.

**https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css**

But as expected the page breaks in lots of places. So what my problem is how can I make the inputs and buttons on a noon bootstrap page looks like bootstrap way. Only the buttons and inputs.

Comment: Have you tried customizing your bootstrap download: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing!

Go over to [bootstrap customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and then tick off everything but the buttons, add the button classes to your buttons and you're done!

Comment: Thats nice.. Just a clarification. So to get this work I've to refer the bootstrap js and CSS.. Right? But I found two css  files in the folder. bootstrap-theme.min.css and bootstrap.min.css. Which among this to refer. I tried referring  both but it breakes apparently everything in my page. From the customizer I had chosen button only (And few components like pagination, pager button groups etc)

Comment: Refer bootstrap.min.css by itself. You can see an example of what the bootstrap theme file does [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/)

Comment: Also you should have ticked off all the js stuff when building your customize bootstrap theme. You don't really need any of the js stuff considering you are just using the CSS for the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a very similar problem recently, I found you can actually download the components individually without using the whole framework.
[Customize and download bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Hope this helps, let me know how you get on

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, don't have the rep to simply comment.

But for the input fields you will also want to select forms too.

Then you can go through the CSS file that is downloaded and pick those you want.

Or an example styling class to start work with:

```
.example
{
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background: #ff671d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

You will need to play around with the properties to get what you want.